# jQuery.ajax access file outside root directory

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can i use jQuery.ajax({ url:"url"});to access a file outside root directory?

Comment: Do you mean on a different domain?

Comment: Smacks of cross-site scripting.

Comment: Could you give an example? Generally: If your files are within the same domain as the script and available through a regular HTTP request to the (current) user, you can access them with AJAX as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ajax` method to access anything visible to the web. However, if you do this then you're likely to fall foul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This usually prevents you from doing an AJAX request outside of your own domain.

However, you can set your requests to be treated as JSONP. This is how you can use JavaScript to get Twitter results, etc.

Go to the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) and scroll down to see the discussion on JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to access any file on your domain that would be available by typing it into a web browser's address bar.  You cannot access files that are outside `/public_html` any more than you would by pointing your web browser at them.

Indeed, you wouldn't want to -- any user can simulate an AJAX request, and would then be able to see any of your server's configuration files!

You will need to write a server-side script that will proxy your request, or just move the relevant file into the `public_html` directory or a subdirectory thereof.

Answer (score 0):

If the url is of the same domain then you can issue an AJAX request to that.