# Jquery.ajax access file outside public_html folder

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jquery file is in /public_html/js/jquery.js i want to access a file outside the public_html directory.How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.ajax access file outside root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646192/jquery-ajax-access-file-outside-root-directory)

Comment: You just asked this question somewhere else. If you want to update a previous question, hit the "edit" link, so that all the responses will be in the same place.

Answer (score 3):

You can't if the folder you're trying to access isn't available to the web. JavaScript is run on the client side so it can only access what the client can (i.e. if you can't get to it through the browser, you won't be able to get to it using JavaScript/jQuery).